# How do I find similar things when a user types a item in a search bar and show them recommended things for their search query?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing this for a project I am challenging myself to do and I have found myself stumped and still have not coded anything. Can anyone help me?

Nothing yet because I am stumped on what to start with

Comment: What kind of "things" are you wanting to show? Are they already on a webpage? Are they in your database?

Comment: I am wanting to show recommended things that I have put in an array

Comment: Please show what you have so far, including your array.

Comment: You can loop through each element of an array and compare that element to the search string. A [minimal working example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help us better understand your problem.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow, I'd suggest taking a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-parser and then you can show them the google results.